# Tag Gutenberg Questions with Popular Package Names?

Tags: discussion, tags

How would y'all feel about tagging Gutenberg questions with some of the more popular [package names](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages)? e.g.

- `@wordpress/env`
- `@wordpress/data` (synonym `redux`?)
- `@wordpress/element` (synonym `react`?)
- `@wordpress/scripts` (synonyms `webpack`, `babel`?)
- `@wordpress/block-editor` (synonym `block-editor`)
- `@wordpress/components`
- `@wordpress/edit-site` (synonym `site-editor`?)
- `@wordpress/edit-widgets` (synonym `widget-editor`?)
- `@wordpress/edit-navigation` (synonym `navigation-editor`?)

I feel that this sort of fits in-line with current tagging practices, as significant number of out popular tags naturally correlate with [the WordPress Core Components](https://make.wordpress.org/core/components/). I think package names work well for classification as well as it distinguishes the subject matter from the traditional and PHP-API-centric subjects or other things which the topics might be confused for (e.g. `scripts` vs `@wordpress/scripts`, `wp_nav_menu`s vs `@wordpress/edit-navigation`, `env` or `wp-env` for general environments). And *I think* the package names are fairly recognizable to anyone who's been working with Gutenberg for a bit.

Alternately, the script handles/shorthands for these packages might be more favorable just for being less verbose (e.g. `wp-env`, `wp-scripts`, `wp-data`, etc.), but I think they're also more ambiguous.

I've only really recently returned in any meaningful capacity so I'm not entirely sure how prevalent Gutenberg questions have been, but I expect they'll become much more prevalent in the next few years.

Comment: I would advise against most of the synonyms as they could be misleading. For example wp element can be mapped on to vue components, wp data has different behaviour to redux, you can use webpack and babel without WP Scripts, the block editor package can be used outside of the block editor, etc etc

Comment: Strong point on all accounts - it does sound as though they'd be unnecessarily misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `block-editor` covers these questions well enough for now, and the confusion mentioned by Tom would just move one level up.

There is also the problem that these names are begging for misuse. Someone not familiar with the block editor might (will!) use these tags for their question about the navigation, some scripts, widgets and so on. The tags wouldn't really help to filter relevant questions anymore, and that's what they are for after all.

I also don't see anyone retagging more than 1.000 existing questions. :)

Comment: A good sanity check. Admittedly my reasons were somewhat selfish - it would be nice to be able to more easily filter and notify for the domains I know or am interested in within Gutenberg. But it does seem unlikely that the community would be naturally inclined to use such tags - and certainly not correctly at that. I do worry about `block-editor`'s rapidly increasing scope, but this is likely a non-issue; at least not yet. If and when it does get broken up, I will certainly commit to chipping away at a retagging backlog :) . Maybe best to leave well enough alone for now though, sure 